# Pageview controller scrolling issue when pageview is inside another pageview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app in which I am using Page View Controllers for multiple pages. There is a main page view controller which contains 3 pages.

My 3rd page from main page view controller is also a page view controller which has 5 pages inside it.

My problem is when I swipe between those 5 pages of child page view controller, sometimes from 2nd or 3rd page it directly swipes to main page.

It should swipe to main page only when I am on 1st page of child page view controller. So when I am swiping between my child view controllers, my main page view controller's data source - delegate methods get called which I don't want.

So how to prevent overlapping between multiple page view controllers in this case?

**EDIT**
How to distinguish swipe between two page view controllers?

Comment: check the child scroll length

Comment: Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: update some code here. it will help to get the answer?

Comment: Code is like this link http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/. Sorry as my code not starting.

Comment: It is as simple as there are 3 pages and 3 page is also a pageviewcontroller like main page holding 5 pages but swiping between those 5 pages, sometimes it takes main page views swipe methods not the child one's.

Comment: you have 5 main page. each and evey mainpage  holding  5 child page. but some time directly move to the 3 child page to next main page, child page have 5 page ? my understanding is right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115733/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-manthan).

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P: u there???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting my main page view controller's data source to null when I am on child page view controller and setting it again when needed solved my issue.

Thanks.